# Install and configure UEC error

Tags: uec

Everything moves fine but when I try to intall the image from image store it shows some error rather than images any one can help me in solving it:

> Error 60: server certificate verification failed. CAfile:
>   /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

Comment: After using the commands as given in [@nijanthanh's](http://askubuntu.com/users/52739/nijanthanh) [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/117382/114818) we just need to obtain the credentials again following the instructions mentioned in [Step 5 as given in Ubuntu Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/CDInstall#STEP_5:_Obtain_Credentials).

Answer (score 3):

Quick and insecure fix WARNING: the change disables certificate validation. Use at your own risk.

Until PycURL is fixed you can edit file /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/imagestore/lib/fetch.py on fetch method after the line 142 add

```
curl.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
curl.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
```

Restart the image-store-proxy

And also update godaddy certificates:

```
sudo wget -P /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ --no-check-certificate https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/gd-class2-root.crt https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/gd_intermediate.crt https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/gd_cross_intermediate.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Comment: The second part about godaddy totally helped me on Debian 7.8 (Readynas OS 6.22)